# TypeScript + Property 'nothing' does not exist on type '<T>(x: T)

Tags: typescript, option-type, monads

I'm trying to hone my Typescript monad skills, so I have created a version of the Maybe monad that technically seems to be working at this point, but Typescript is complaining that  `Property 'nothing' does not exist on type '<T>(x: T)`

Here is my function:

```
const Nothing = Symbol('Nothing');

export const Maybe = <T>(x: T) => ({
  map: <U>(f: Function) => Maybe(f(x)),
  nothing: <T>() => Maybe(Nothing),
  fold: <U>({ just, nothing }: { just: (x: T) => U; nothing: () => U }): U =>
    x === Nothing ? nothing() : just(x as T),
  flatMap: <U>(f: (x: T) => U): typeof Maybe | typeof Nothing =>
    x === Nothing ? Maybe.nothing() : f(x),
});
```

In Maybe.nothing() inside of the flatMap function is what is throwing the error.
[image: maybe screengrab]

I was wondering if I need to try to create an interface for this function, but not quite sure what the correct fix for this would be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide us which version of TS do you use ?

Comment: typescript version is 4.5.4

Comment: There's a lot of weird stuff going on in this code example, but I'll only focus on what you're asking about. The error is warning you of an actual problem, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaDjEw) `Maybe(Nothing).flatMap(x => x)` will throw a runtime error.  Indeed, `Maybe.nothing` does not exist; `Maybe` is a function as you presumably intend, and while it *returns* something with a `nothing` property, it doesn't have one itself.  (more)

Comment: (continued) So you need to fix it somehow, maybe by returning `Maybe(Nothing)` instead of `Maybe.nothing()`.  But then you will have other problems, quite a few of them, it looks like, so we should stop there.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?